# Java: How to Set Bounds on Class Type Field in Enum

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have an enum which has a property that is another class.  I want to somewhere put a constraint that all instances of the enum have should have a value for that property that extend a certain upper bound, in this case an interface.  Here is the basic working example without the bound:

```
public enum MyClassRegistry
{
    MyClass(1,com.example.MyClass.class)

    private int typeId;
    private Class theClass;
}
```

What I want to do next is something like:

```
public enum MyClassRegistry 
{
    MyClass(1,com.example.MyClass.class)

    private int typeId;
    private Class<T extends SomeInterface> theClass;
}
```

To enforce that all values of this field extend a certain upper bound.  Is this possible?  If so, what is the syntax for this?

Comment: Wait, do you want `Class` instances or instances of the class represented by that `Class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public enum MyClassRegistry
{
    MyClass(1,com.example.MyClass);

    private int typeId;
    private Class<? extends SomeInterface> theClass;

    MyClassRegistry(int typeId, Class<? extends SomeInterface> theClass) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
        this.theClass = theClass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `enum` type cannot declare any generic type parameters.

If you mean you want to have a field that has a type of some super type, an interface for example, simply declare the field as having that type.

```
public enum MyClassRegistry
{
    First(1, new InterfaceFirstImpl()),
    Second(2, new InterfaceSecondImpl()) ;

    MyClassRegistry (int id, Interface value) {
        this.typeId = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
    private int typeId;
    private Interface value;
}
```